# java script if else statement if i "=" 0でも数回出力する。

Tags: javascript

if（i = 0) でも　以下のJavaScriptコードが内容を実行するのはなぜですか？　if(  "==")でなければならないことを知っていますが。 "I'm"と "A" "A" "A"...という出力を得ることができます。PythonやJavaで見たことがないと思います。

```js
function titleCase(str) {
      var array = str.split(" ");
      var str1 = "";
      var i = 0;
      while(i < array.length){
          str = array[i]
          if(i = 0){
               console.log(str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1));
          }else{
               console.log(console.log(str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)));
          }
          i++;
      }
      console.log(str1)
    }
    
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(i = 0)`で毎回iに0が代入されてるのに、whileを抜ける条件が『array.lengthより大きくなったら』だからです。
iは1までしか増えないので永遠にloopを抜けれません。

---

strを取得するタイミングではiは1なので、strにはaが入ってます。
if文でiは0になります。

if文は、`i = 0`の結果である0を評価します。0はfalseとして扱われるので、`console.log(console.log(str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1)));`しか実行されませんね。

と、いうわけで2回目のloop以降は、永遠にAが出力され続けませんか？

Comment: なるほど if else statementの中 でもi = 0 を 毎回 assign してしまうんですね。勉強になりました。java、pythonでは確かエラーなので思いつきませんでした。便利そうですね。

Comment: code行数を減らすためにこういう書き方をする方も居られます。が、意図して`i = 0`としているのか？それとも誤って`i = 0`としているのかが、周りのcodeを読まないと分からない事が多いので、if文中の代入は好まれません。複数人で作業でされるような場合に、この書き方をされるときは、周りの反応を見ながら使ってください。

Comment: @ 豚吐露 ありがとうございます。抽象的になるので、グループでやるとすると、上級者同士ではないと使いづらそうですね。